# Company account terminated

Tags: google-account

I had my work gmail setup on my phone. I just switched jobs and I got a notification that I've been signed out of my account (the account activity required notification). I click it and it's trying to get me to sign in under the old gmail, which is deactivated. I disabled gmail and it still won't go away.

My phone is signed into my personal gmail account. How do I get this notification to go away?

Comment: Without knowing the phone model, you could try removing the old account via Settings - Accounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the account from the phone settings.

Depending on your model and Android version, the location will slightly vary. Try this:

Settings > Users & Accounts (Or only accounts) > That Google work account > Remove account.

Once removed, you should get rid of the notification in your tray.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I couldn't figure out where the account would be accept for the gmail.